# Populate a combobox with table column

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I have to populate a ComboBox with one column from SQlite table

I use this to select Column but I think the query should be a list of strings, how can I cast the  (object) to a list of strings?

```
 public List<string> SystemsNameList()
 {
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
    {
        var SystemsName = conn.Query<FFSystems>("select Name from FFSystems");
        return SystemsName;
    }
}
```

This is the definition of the objects saved in the database table

```
public class FFSystems
    {
        [PrimaryKey][AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IDCode { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string CreationDate { get; set; }
        public FFSystems() { }

        public FFSystems(string name, int idcode, bool active)
        {
            Name = name;
            IDCode = idcode;
            Active = active;
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `SystemsNames.Cast<string>().ToList()` work?

Comment: Nope, I have an InvalidCastExcepion when I use that

Comment: What type is SystemsName?

Comment: SystemsName is an object from a table, but I select only one column of strings with the query.

Comment: Yes, but what is its type... object, FFSystems, SystemsName, something else? I would guess Name is stored as a string in the database, but I am unsure of how to cast SystemsName to a string because I don't know its type. If the type is actually "SystemsName", then what property is Name stored in SystemsName?

Comment: I modified the code in the post, I think SystemsName is a FFsystems object because i've declered it there for the first time in the method.

Comment: Can you post the definition of FFSystems or what property FFSystems stores Name in? If you're not sure its FFSystems, just hover over "var" to see what the type is.

Comment: I've updated the post with object definition

Comment: try `return SystemsName.Select(n => n.Name).ToList();`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot

Comment: Awesome! I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the property in FFSystems that is storing the name. 
You can use LINQ to get it easily.

`return SystemsName.Select(n => n.Name).ToList();`